# J2me reading file while writing it?

Tags: file, java-me

Using J2me, is it possible to read from a file while another thread is writing to it? 
Or the writing operation locks the file and prevents the read operation ? 
i.e. I'm asking about the possibility of reading & writing in same time.

Comment: I bet this is the sort of thing that will vary between handsets.  Have you tried it to see what happens?

Comment: Why not give it a wee shot and see how you get on?  Report back here when you find out!

Comment: I tried it on Curve 8520 & Bold 9100, reading and writing operations terminated successfully without any problems :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it on Curve 8520: reading and writing operations terminated successfully without any problems.
So I think, the answer is **"yes this can be done"**.
But can't test it on all devices (i.e. I can't be sure it's device independent), perhaps when running on other devices it may cause a problem; as happened with [Mihir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/491978/mihir) in a previous comment in this discussion thread !!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible.
You can read from a file while another thread is writing in to that file
but it is not advisable.

i had mad same kind of application in which sometimes read and write both were done on same file. When this situation occur it was **removing** that file from device.

So it is better to set lock on file.

Comment: How do you say "it is possible", despite that you say "it was removing that file from device" ?  If it is removing the file then it's not possible ..... more explanation please ....

Comment: i say possible in terms of that jvm will not restrict you from doing that but it will result in file remove.